# Ipython notebook inside pycharm with remote interpreter doesn't start

Tags: python, pycharm, jupyter-notebook

Working on Pycharm(4.5.1) on windows with remote interpreter using python install on linux machine.

my remote interpreter works fine with normal python stuff.

Ipython notebook not working.. followed below documentation
https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PYH/Using+IPython+Notebook+with+PyCharm

after the PyCharm shows a dialog box, where you have to specify the URL where the IPython Notebook server will run:..

Not getting confirmaation and url doesn't work.

No bugs reported on this at this time of writing...